# How to Hide a division on form submit in PHP if the validations that are checked from the database side are correct?

Tags: php, javascript, validation, html

Im quite new to php development. In the application Im having a **home.php** page where the user needs to enter a security code and submit. 
If the entered security code is correct then the 2 divisions should be hide from the user (the div ids are window and security) 
The security card validations are being done using the **securityValidation.class.php**. 
the securityValidation.class.php class contains a method call **validateSecuiryCode**. It accepts the code and checks the validity in the database and if exits it sends 1 else 0.

**Can someone help me with  hiding the 2 divisions in the html part on submit if the validations are true.** 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Read about [jQuery](http://jquery.com), a very good solution for your problem!

Comment: Im confused about calling a function inside a php page in the ajax function. In most examples available they call a php page, but not a function. Any one has an idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have a request in ajax where it ask the securityValidation.class.php? I always do like this. I made a file called `ajax.php`, then you add the database connection file, maybe if exists a functions-file. Then with help of `$_GET` I do a smart selection. I'll show you a example!

```
//The ajax.php
<?php
include('conn.php');
include('functions.php');
if($_GET['a']) //My alias in the url
{
    switch($_GET['a'])
    {
      case 'validateSecuiryCode':
      //Include or anything what you want to do... Do make a return that only echo 1 or 0.
      break;
    }
}
?>
```

This is the request `ajax.php?a=validateSecuiryCode&code=1234141431`

```
//The jQuery request to ajax.php
$(document).ready(function(){ //The DOM
$('#submit').click(function(){
var theCodeVal = $('#the_input_for_the_valid_code').val();
$.get('ajax.php',{"a":"validateSecuiryCode","code":theCodeVal},function(result){
if(result==1)
{
   //The thing if validate code is right
}
else
{
   //The thing if not valid code
}
});
});
});
```

This is a simplified example how to make an ajax request to a php-function and then present the return or maybe run a specific js-function.